# Оптимизация left join

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, с оптимизацией запроса:

```
SELECT * , b.`id` AS bid, u.`id` AS uid, cd.`open_n` , cd.`close_n` 
FROM  `bills` AS b
LEFT JOIN  `users` u ON u.`id` = b.`author` 
LEFT JOIN  `close_docs` cd ON cd.`bill_id` = b.`id` 
WHERE b.`check` !=  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
LIMIT 1303 , 30
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED выдает:

[image]

В `close_docs` не всегда есть строки, соответствующие `b.id`.
В `bills` и `close_docs` около 3500 записей, запрос выполняется около 25 секунд.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
Select *, b.`id` AS bid, u.`id` AS uid, cd.`open_n` , cd.`close_n` 
from `bills` as b, `users` as u, `close_docs` as cd
Where b.`check`!=  "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and u.`id`=b.`autor` and cd.`bill_id` = b.`id`
```

Создайте внешний ключ на cd.`bill_id` = b.`id`, это ускорит.

Comment: Это все хорошо, но есть проблема, что в `close_docs` не всегда есть записи, поэтому часть строк не участвует в выборке. Плюсанул и обновил вопрос.

Comment: Внешний ключ в любом случае стоит создать)

Comment: значит JOIN должен быть открытым 

LEFT OUTER JOIN  `close_docs` cd ON cd.`bill_id` = b.`id`

Comment: left - всегда outer) не бывает left inner join )

Comment: Чтоб меня за ногу, работает, спасибо. Указал `foreign key`, оставив `left join`'ы. А где можно почитать про механизм работы `foreign key`, желательно на понятном языке?

Comment: Сколько теперь времени требуется?

Comment: у Вас в ответе соединение в старом стиле и оно закрытое

Comment: @timka_s, сейчас 0.028 секунды. Грубо - ускорение в 1000 раз.

Comment: @ling, 3500/log2(3500) = 450, почти как в теории))